# Using iText 7 in module

Tags: java, itext, itext7, jdeps

I am trying a modular project in Java 16 and I want to test out iText7.
As far as I can see, the jars of iText7 are compiled against Java8.
So I have to update the jar-files of iText7 with jdeps aso. But it does not work.
Is there an easier way to use iText7 in a Java > 8 project?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly prevents you from using iText 7 in a Java 9+ project? The fact that it was compiled against Java 8 alone should not be a blocker, should it?

Comment: When I'm in my IDE, everything works fine. But I try to generate an appimage. And then, it says, that the itext JAR files cannot be processed by jlink, cause they are not automatic modules or so.

Comment: You may want to add all those details into your question

Comment: Could be e.g. feature request for jlink. iText 7 does not feature Java 9+ module-info declarations at the moment but this should not be a blocker for using iText 7 on higher Java versions

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I tried to use jlink on it, but itext has so many dependencies, that I gave up. It is only a problem, when you want to create an appimage or rpm or exe or alike.
Right now, I have written my own printing class, which suits my needs, so I wait until itext is ready for appimage and Java 9+.
But thanks for your help!!